# What is a police car?

Tags: united-states, california, police, massachusetts

Is a police department allowed to duct tape lights and a siren to a private vehicle and start using it as a police cruiser? If the only law in question is whether one is "impersonating an officer," can any car drive around with lights and sirens blaring so long as there's a public or private police officer in it?

*I'm really curious about how this applies everywhere, but considering I split primary residence between California and Boston, I'm including tags for California, Massachusetts, and the US.*

Comment: Why would you expect this to violate laws about impersonating a police officer? What leads you to suspect that any of this might fall afoul of the law?

Comment: (Beyond traffic laws about improperly secured cargo)

Comment: For one, [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/61470/932) to a question about whether making a fake police car would be illegal in the state of Oregon. I couldn't find clear definitions of what constitutes a police car in California and Massachusetts, and I'm not sure if it's even defined, even though creating one _without_ the involvement of a police department would apparently be illegal

Comment: Who owns the car? Do the police have the owner's consent? What insurance cover is there? Is this an officially sanctioned police policy? Is there a risk assessment in place? Why are they doing it in the first place?

Comment: @Sneftel Yes, there are also laws against having flashing blue lights except on a police vehicle, and so on. I think questioning the possiblity of legal liability is quite well-founded.

Answer (score 5):

A "police car" doesn't necessarily have a special legal status, so a police officer can theoretically drive a beat-up pickup truck and "be legal" (but not in Washington, see below). What matters is whether others have to give special attention to the vehicle. The pertinent question is, what are the requirements for being an authorized emergency vehicle. I'll give you Washington state law, and you can apply this to other states fairly easily.

[RCW 46.37.190(1)](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=46.37.190) mandates that

> Every authorized emergency vehicle shall, in addition to any other
> equipment and distinctive marking required by this chapter, be
> equipped with at least one lamp capable of displaying a red light
> visible from at least five hundred feet in normal sunlight and a siren
> capable of giving an audible signal.
>
> (3) Vehicles operated by public agencies whose law enforcement duties
> include the authority to stop and detain motor vehicles on the public
> highways of the state may be equipped with a siren and lights of a
> color and type designated by the state patrol for that purpose. The
> state patrol may prohibit the use of these sirens and lights on
> vehicles other than the vehicles described in this subsection.

Given these restrictions, a driver knows whether they must get out of the way, and whether they have to "pull over" (stop driving and get ready for a brief traffic detention).

The manner of attachment of "stuff" on the outside of the vehicle falls under general state patrol safety rules, whereby for example you can't balance a rocking chair on the roof and speed down the highway. The state patrol has reasonable discretion to deem that a particular mode of attachment is "unsafe" – this won't be like building-code minutia. Duck tape would probably be deemed to be an insecure means of attachment.

There can be some statutory provisions regarding use of private vehicles, for example [RCW 46.37.185](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=46.37.185) allows green lights on firefighter's private care:

> Firefighters, when approved by the chief of their respective service,
> shall be authorized to use a green light on the front of their private
> cars when on emergency duty only. Such green light shall be visible
> for a distance of two hundred feet under normal atmospheric conditions
> and shall be of a type and mounting approved by the Washington state
> patrol. The use of the green light shall only be for the purpose of
> identification and the operator of a vehicle so equipped shall not be
> entitled to any of the privileges provided in RCW 46.61.035 for the
> operators of authorized emergency vehicles.

Flashing blue lights are prohibited by [WAC 204-21-230(c)(4)](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/WAc/default.aspx?cite=204-21-230) "other than a law enforcement vehicle as defined in [WAC 204-21-020](https://app.leg.wa.gov/WAC/default.aspx?cite=204-21-020)", which is "a publicly owned or leased vehicle operated by a law enforcement agency and which is used for the law enforcement functions of the agency". That means that in Washington, the town sheriff cannot use his personal car as a law enforcement vehicle. I expect there to be some variation on that point across the US.

The lights-and-sirens law is what keeps ordinary people from putting lights and sirens on their vehicles.